# Showing HTML at particular point

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

Some plot points in my dataset need to be highlighted.  Ideally I would like to be able to do the following:

- Id like to display arbitary HTML at a particular X location (with a Y of my choosing)
- Id like to replace certain markers with HTML

Is this possible? I cannot seem to find any documentation on how to do it?

Comment: I am not sure what you would like to achieve here. Maybe you can use marker.symbol parameter in this case? http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-marker-symbol/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński Thanks for the reply and sorry for the delay.  This is exactly what I want, except I want to be able to display a sun, or icon (HTML) at a specific point rather than all of them.  This will be used to highlight events.

Comment: So you can add marker.symbol inside specific point: http://jsfiddle.net/rw2xybee/ If this example will meet your requirements I will post it as an answer

Comment: That'd be great, but can I use HTML as opposed to an image?

Comment: You can use fontAwesome like shown in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/2A7Zf/80/